# How to use scala case class as function parameter to specify different fields to use?

Tags: scala, case-class

I have some duplication of code due to having to do some grouping on 3 different fields in a case class and then populate a new case class with those. Since they share a common schema it should be possible for me to do a function that can take the input of the 3 different fields and populate accordingly. However, I am not exactly sure how to do this.

**Schemas:**

```
case class Transaction(
  senderBank: Bank,
  receiverBank: Bank,
  intermediaryBank: Bank)

case class Bank(
  name: String,
  country: Option[String],
  countryCode: Option[String])

case class GroupedBank(
  name: String,
  country: Option[String],
  countryCode: Option[String],
  bankType: String)
```

**Current function I tried to do:**

```
def groupedBank(transactionSeq: Seq[Transaction], bankName: Bank, bankTypeString: String): Iterable[Seq[GroupedBank]] = {
 transactionSeq.groupBy(_ => bankName.name).map {
  case (key, transactionSeq) =>
    val bankGroupedSeq = transactionSeq.map(_ => {
      GroupedBank(
        name = bankName.name,
        country = bankName.country,
        countryCode = bankName.countryCode,
        bankType = bankTypeString)
    })
    bankGroupedSeq
  }
}
```

I need to do the grouping for `SenderBank`, `receiverBank`, and `intermediaryBank`. However, I am not sure how to refer to them correctly in the function parameter `bankName`. So for `SenderBank` I would want to do something like `Transaction.senderBank`, which would point to the correct fields for name, country and so on for `senderBank`. For `receiverBank` it should be similar, so `Transactions.receiverBank`, which then refers to the correct fields for `receiverBank` and so on. And again for `intermediaryBank` the same logic. My question is therefore how can I accomplish something like this or is there another way that would be more appropriate?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you're doing. Do you want `transactionSeq.groupBy(_.senderBank.name)`, `transactionSeq.groupBy(_.receiverBank.name)`, `transactionSeq.groupBy(_.intermediaryBank.name)`?

Comment: @DmytroMitin, yes exactly. Sorry that I was a bit unclear.

Comment: @DmytroMitin, but how would this look like in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to extract the bank with the correct type from a transaction:

```
def groupedBank(
  transactionSeq: Seq[Transaction], 
  getBank: Transaction => Bank, 
  bankTypeString: String
): Iterable[Seq[GroupedBank]] = {
  transactionSeq.groupBy(getBank(_).name).map {
    case (key, transactionSeq) =>
      transactionSeq.map { transaction =>
        val bank = getBank(transaction)
        GroupedBank(
          name = bank.name,
          country = bank.country,
          countryCode = bank.countryCode,
          bankType = bankTypeString)
      }
  }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
groupedBank(transactionSeq, _.senderBank, "sender")
```

---

It could also be a good idea to abstract the bank type concept into a separate trait:

```
sealed trait BankGroup {
  def name: String
  def getBank(transaction: Transaction): Bank

  def groupBanks(transactionSeq: Seq[Transaction]): Iterable[Seq[GroupedBank]] = {
    transactionSeq.groupBy(getBank(_).name).map {
      case (key, transactionSeq) =>
        transactionSeq.map { transaction =>
          val bank = getBank(transaction)
          GroupedBank(
            name = bank.name,
            country = bank.country,
            countryCode = bank.countryCode,
            bankType = name)
        }
    }
  }
}

object BankGroup {
  object Sender extends BankGroup {
    def name: String = "sender"
    def getBank(transaction: Transaction): Bank = transaction.senderBank
  }

  object Receiver extends BankGroup {
    def name: String = "receiver"
    def getBank(transaction: Transaction): Bank = transaction.receiverBank
  }

  object Intermediary extends BankGroup {
    def name: String = "intermediary"
    def getBank(transaction: Transaction): Bank = transaction.intermediaryBank
  }

  val values: Seq[BankGroup] = Seq(Sender, Receiver, Intermediary)
  def byName(name: String): BankGroup = values.find(_.name == name)
    .getOrElse(sys.error(s"unknown bank type: $name"))
}
```

And you can call it in one of those ways:

```
BankGroup.Sender.groupBanks(transactionSeq)
BankGroup.byName("sender").groupBanks(transactionSeq)
```